# Using setCurrentItem when slidetab is inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, swipe

My application has to swipe in between fragments when a button is pressed. If I was hosting swipe tab and view pager inside an activity, I would do something like this.

```
((ParentActivityName) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(2, true);
```

Now I have a parent Fragment that hosts the slide tabs. It has the following method to set current child Fragment to viewpager.

```
public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}
```

On Click of "Next" button in one of the sliding tab Fragments, I am trying to call the method as

```
new FragUserRegistration().setCurrentItem(1,true);
```

But is simply returning a null object reference error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I worked it out simply by calling viewpager from parent Fragment to each sliding tab fragments and then the associated setCurrentItem method.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(int position, true);    
//four swipe-able fragments so position - -> 1-3 (total count 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your click happens to set the current item. 
Maybe you'll find this useful:

Your MainFragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //init view
MainViewPageAdapter mainViewPageAdapter = new MainViewPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    yourViewPager.setAdapter(mainViewPageAdapter);
    return view;
}

 private class MainViewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final int MAX_COUNT = 2;

    public MainViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                fragment = YourChildFragmentOne.getInstance();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = YourChildFragmentTwo.getInstance();
                break;
          }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MAX_COUNT;
    }
}
```

In your ChildFragment(s):

(or create an abstract ChildFragment, which handles the click listener and create two instances of the abstract one)

```
private OnChildFragmentClickListener mClickListener;

    @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mClickListener = (OnChildFragmentClickListener) getParentFragment();
}

//call somewhere in your ChildFragment mClickListener.onChildFragClick(index);

public interface OnChildFragmentClickListener{
 void onChildFragClick(int index);
}
```

Now let your MainFragment implement OnChildFragmentClickListener and call there:

```
@Override
public void onChildFragClick(int index){
yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
}
```

Comment: I think it wud be an unnecessary hassle to implement interface in all child fragments just to make the viewpager slide when a button is pressed in each fragment. I found a simpler solution by simply calling the viewpager from parent fragment to child and then calling the setCurrentItem method associated with the viewpager. 

    viewPager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);

Thank you for your response. Will keep in mind to use interfaces for future purpose.

Comment: Your use case wasn't clear to me, I understood, that you click somewhere in your child fragment and the ViewPager switches to an other fragment. That's the way from bottom to top in architecture hierarchy where usually interfaces are used bc of loose coupling. 
And you don't have to declare in all child fragments an interface, that's why the hint for an abstract fragment.  
Maybe you could share your solution with us, to help other people!?

Comment: Yeah sure. Just did that :)